# System Languages Mess

Tags: language-support, gnome-do

A friend installed Ubuntu for me in spanish.
I would like to switch it back to english. I tried the "apply system wide" but now it seems I messed something up, because now some things are in english and some instructions remain in spanish. Is there a way to even this out? What I would like to do is set the system language to english and all text editions to spanish, is that possible?

Maybe re-install Ubuntu in english over?

Also, I installed GNome Do and each time I try to set the activation keys, it wont remember them.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Language support, and make sure that both the Language tab, and Regional Format tab are both set to English.  I would also recommend that you go into the Keyboard layout, just to make sure English is there.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try selecting English, Applying System-Wide, then remove Spanish from the computer. If that does not work, I would advise reinstalling... as Ubuntu might have installed all Spanish versions of the system applications.

Hope this helps.